# If Simpson's paradox occurs, then is the stratified variable a confounder?

Tags: probability, inequality, optimization

Let $f(a,b,c,d) := ad - bc$.
Does there exist positive integers $a,b,c,d,a^\prime, b^\prime,c^\prime,d^\prime$ such that
$$f(a,b,c,d) >0,f(a^\prime,b^\prime, c^\prime, d^\prime) > 0,  f(a+a^\prime, b + b^\prime, c+ c^\prime, d+d^\prime) < 0 \text{ and } \qquad (*)$$
$$f(a + c, a^\prime + c^\prime, b + d, b^\prime + d^\prime) \neq 0?$$

---

**Motivation.** Two boolean variables $X$ and $Y$ are *positively associated* if $\mathrm{rate}(X \mid Y) > \mathrm{rate}(X \mid \neg Y)$, *negatively associated* if $\mathrm{rate}(X \mid Y) < \mathrm{rate}(X \mid \neg Y)$, and *associated* if they are either positively associated or negatively associated. Here $\mathrm{rate}(A \mid B) := \#(A \wedge B)/\#B$. Given a contingency table,
$$\matrix{\phantom{XX} & Y & \neg Y}$$
$$\matrix{X \\ \neg X}\matrix{a & b \\ c & d}$$
i.e. $\#(X \wedge Y) = a, \#(X \wedge \neg Y) = b, \#(\neg X \wedge Y) = c$ and $\# (\neg X \wedge \neg Y) = d$,
the variables $X$ and $Y$ are positively associated if and only if $f(a,b,c,d) := ad - bc > 0$ and negatively associated if and only if $f(a,b,c,d) < 0$.

Given a third boolean variable $Z$, *Simpson's paradox* is said to occur if the sign of the association is reversed upon stratifying along a third boolean variable $Z$, i.e. if $X \wedge Z$ is positively associated to $Y \wedge Z$, and $X \wedge \neg Z$ is positively associated to $Y \wedge \neg Z$, but $X$ is negatively associated to $Y$ (c.f. $(*)$ above).

A variable $Z$ is said to *confound* the association between $X$ and $Y$ if $Z$ is associated to $X$, and $Z$ is associated to $Y$. Typically, stratification is done as a means of controlling for a variable $Z$ which confounds the association between $X$ and $Y$. If Simpson's paradox occurs, then does the stratified variable $Z$ necessarily confound the association between $X$ and $Y$? In particular, the above question asks whether if Simpson's paradox occurs, is it necessary that the stratified variable $Z$ is associated to $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two following matrices $M$ and $M'$ do the job:
$$M=\left[\matrix{3&9\cr1&6\cr}\right]\>,\qquad 
M'=\left[\matrix{6&1\cr9&3\cr}\right]\ .$$
Then
$$\det M=\det M'=9>0,\qquad\det(M+M')=\det\left[\matrix{9&10\cr10&9\cr}\right]=-19<0\ ,$$
and
$$\det\left[\matrix{a+c&a'+c'\cr b+d&b'+d'\cr}\right]=\det\left[\matrix{4&15\cr15&4\cr}\right]\ne0\ .$$

Comment: Thanks, Professor Blatter! We also have $\det \left[ \matrix{ a + b & a^\prime + b^\prime \\ c + d & c^\prime + d^\prime}\right] = \det \left[ \matrix{12 & 7 \\ 7 & 12} \right] \neq 0$. Therefore the stratified variable is a confounder in this example.